# Difficulty displaying histogram for every variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, histogram, data-mining

I need to plot histograms for `numeric` variables, in order to determine if their distributions are skewed. Below is the function definition, and the function being called.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

def variable_type(df, nominal_level = 3):
    categorical, numeric, nominal = [],[],[]
    for variable in df.columns.values:
        if np.issubdtype(np.array(df[variable]).dtype, int) or np.issubdtype(np.array(df[variable]).dtype, float): #if srray variable is of type int or float
            if len(np.unique(np.array(df[variable]))) <= nominal_level:
                nominal.append(variable)
            else:
                numeric.append(variable)
        else:
            categorical.append(variable)
    return numeric,categorical,nominal
def draw_histograms(df, variables, n_rows, n_cols):
    fig = plt.figure()
    import math
    for i in range(min(n_rows * n_cols, len(variables))):
        index = n_rows * 100 + n_cols * 10 + i + 1
        ax = fig.add_subplot(index)
        df[variables[i]].hist(bins = 20, ax = ax)
        plt.title(variables[i]+' distribution')
        #plt.xlabel(variables[i])
        #plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.show()

def main():
    df = read_data()
    col_names = df.columns.tolist()
    numeric,categorical,nominal = variable_type(df) 
    util.draw_histograms(df, numeric, 3, 3)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My program only works when I use 3, 3 for `n_rows` and `n_cols` in the calling function, and this is a problem because it only plots 9 of the 20 variables. If I try any other numbers, I get a `ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 18, not 0` or some other range depending on my chosen `n_rows` and `n_cols`. What can I do to plot all 20 numeric variables as subplots on one figure? or should I break it into different figures? This is a sample of my data frame.

```
   TARGET_B      ID  GiftCnt36  GiftCntAll  GiftCntCard36  GiftCntCardAll  \
0         0   14974          2           4              1               3   
1         0    6294          1           8              0               3   
2         1   46110          6          41              3              20   
3         1  185937          3          12              3               8   
4         0   29637          1           1              1               1   

   GiftAvgLast  GiftAvg36  GiftAvgAll  GiftAvgCard36      ...       \
0           17      13.50        9.25          17.00      ...        
1           20      20.00       15.88            NaN      ...        
2            6       5.17        3.73           5.00      ...        
3           10       8.67        8.50           8.67      ...        
4           20      20.00       20.00          20.00      ...        

   PromCntCardAll  StatusCat96NK  StatusCatStarAll  DemCluster  DemAge  \
0              13              A                 0           0     NaN   
1              24              A                 0          23      67   
2              22              S                 1           0     NaN   
3              16              E                 1           0     NaN   
4               6              F                 0          35      53   

   DemGender  DemHomeOwner  DemMedHomeValue DemPctVeterans  DemMedIncome  
0          F             U              $0               0           $0   
1          F             U        $186,800              85           $0   
2          M             U         $87,600              36      $38,750   
3          M             U        $139,200              27      $38,942   
4          M             U        $168,100              37      $71,509
```

Comment: `util`? Is this something you defined?

Comment: Yes. variable_type is defined in a utility class. let me edit my question to avoid any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NaN` in your 10th attribute. Can your code handle this?
An you plot the 10th attribute?

Comment: That's another issue, I need to replace NaN with np.Nan. I tried df.replace('Nan', np.NaN), and that didn't work. How would I replace those NaN values?

Comment: They are still `np.NaN` then, and may cause problems. So, can you plot histogram #10 *at all*?

Comment: No I can't. This are the variables I need to plot. `['ID', 'GiftCnt36', 'GiftCntAll', 'GiftCntCard36', 'GiftCntCardAll', 'GiftAvgLast', 'GiftAvg36', 'GiftAvgAll', 'GiftAvgCard36', 'GiftTimeLast', 'GiftTimeFirst', 'PromCnt12', 'PromCnt36', 'PromCntAll', 'PromCntCard12', 'PromCntCard36', 'PromCntCardAll', 'DemCluster', 'DemAge', 'DemPctVeterans']`, and I can only plot from 'ID' through 'GiftAvgCard36'. These nine variables do plot, despite the Nan values.

Comment: It's confusing, for the assignment I need to plot a histogram with the missing values for a quality check. Once I've used the histogram for . identifingy numeric variables that have skewed distribution and need to be log or sqrt-transformed, then I need to impute missing imputation with dummy values.